# Flutter bottomSheet fade-in, fade-out animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is it possible to implement fade-in and fade-out animation on flutter bottom sheet? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using Flutter Animated Opactity and BottomSheet Widget

```
class MyBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyBottomSheetState createState() => _MyBottomSheetState();
}

class _MyBottomSheetState extends State<MyBottomSheet> {
  bool _showBottomSheet = false;

  void toggleBottomSheet() {
    setState(() {
      _showBottomSheet = !_showBottomSheet;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Toggle Bottom Sheet'),
          onPressed: toggleBottomSheet,
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: _showBottomSheet ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Bottom Sheet Content',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```